# Constructor'PieEntry(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'

Tags: android, listview

I passed an array list value to my other Pie Chart activity, I want to used my arraylist as a PieEntry or Data for my pie Chart but everytime i add my arraylist it always get an error"Cannot Resolve Constructor'PieEntry(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'

i hope you can understand my explanation 
Thankyou!`

[image: this is the error i get]

```
public void setupPieChart(){
    //Populating a List of PieEntries:
    List<PieEntry> pieEntries =new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0;i<Percentage.size(); i++){
        pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(Percentage.get(i), Class[i]));
    }
    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntries, "");
    dataSet.setColors(new int[] {Color.rgb(46,204,113), Color.rgb(177,99,163),Color.rgb(246,195,36),Color.rgb(141,174,215),
            Color.rgb(194,178,128),Color.rgb(118,150,155),Color.rgb(158,157,156),Color.rgb(187,62,24),Color.rgb(232,115,61),
            Color.rgb(155,144,200)});
    PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);


    //get the chart
    PieChart chart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.animateY(1000);
    chart.invalidate();
    chart.setCenterText("Rainfalls");
    //change position of legend
    Legend legend = chart.getLegend();
    legend.setTextSize(12f);
    legend.setXEntrySpace(5f);
    legend.setYEntrySpace(5f);
    legend.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
    legend.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
}`
```

Comment: please show error log

Comment: i already post the image of the error

Comment: sorry i am newbie programmer, what error log?

Comment: ```Percentage.get(i)``` returns a ```String```. The first argument of the constructor of ```PieEntry``` accepts a float value.
Make ```Percentage.get(i)``` return float.

Comment: how ? can you give me an example?

Comment: @C.Oriondo don't you think you should first learn programming concepts and Java.

Comment: okay im sorry i just want to know the error in my program.. so i asked a question here .. sorry